# php array comparison index by index

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

If there are two array variable which contains exact same digits(no duplicate) but shuffled in position.

**Input arrays**

```
arr1={1,4,6,7,8};
arr2={1,7,7,6,8};
```

**Result array**

```
arr2={true,false,false,false,true};
```

Is there a function in php to get result as above or should it be done using loop(which I can do) only.

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself in a loop. PHP has a ton of helper functions, but don't expect to find a ready-made house, when you're given a hammer already.

Comment: These arrays do not have the same exact digits; `arr2` has duplicates.

Comment: @js1568 no duplicate means in both arrays digits are unique in their own.

Comment: @kiranking `arr2={1,7,7,6,8};` has two 7s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice application for [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and an anonymous callback (OK, I must admit that I like those closures ;-)

```
$a1 = array(1,4,6,7,8);
$a2 = array(1,7,7,6,8);

$r = array_map(function($a1, $a2) {
    return $a1 === $a2;
}, $a1, $a2);

var_dump($r);

/*
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(false)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
  [4]=>
  bool(true)
}
*/
```

And yes, you have to loop over the array some way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

You could use array_map:

```
<?php

$arr1= array (1,4,6,7,8) ;
$arr2= array (1,7,7,6,8) ;

function cmp ($a, $b) {
    return $a == $b ;
}

print_r (array_map ("cmp", $arr1, $arr2)) ;
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any way this job is done must be using looping the elements. There is no way to avoid looping.

No metter how you try to attack the problem and even if there is a php function that do such thing, it uses a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php, but it will not return an array of booleans.  It will return what data in array 1 is not in array 2.  If this doesn't work for you, you will have to loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

there's [`array_diff()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which will return an empty array in case they are both equal.

For your spesific request, you'll have to iterate through the arrays and compare each item.