# compaire two array index and if same count

Tags: php

i have two arrays as following

```
$fix=array(2,4,5,6);
$marks=array(2,4,6,8);
```

i want to get if same number has same index in two arrays count it  and i want to get final total as  2,
i wrote some code but it not work
 i refer for this code [php array comparison index by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961723/php-array-comparison-index-by-index)

```
$total=0;
$r = array_map(function($fix, $marks) {
    if( $fix === $marks){

        $total=$total+1;
        return  $total;

        }
}, $fix, $marks);

echo $total;
```

Comment: count(array_intersect_assoc($fix, $marks)); will give what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
$fix=array(2,4,5,6);
$marks=array(2,4,6,8);

$r = array_map(function($fix, $marks) {
    if( $fix === $marks){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}, $fix, $marks);

echo array_sum($r);
```

Output 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect_assoc` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php)

```
$fix=array(2,4,5,6);
$marks=array(2,4,6,8);
echo count(array_intersect_assoc($fix, $marks));
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working

```
$fix=array(2,4,5,6);
$marks=array(1,4,5,6);

    $total=0;

    foreach($fix as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value == $marks[$key])
        {
            $total=$total+1;
        }
    }

    echo $total;
```